# No datastore configured

Tags: simplesamlphp

I have migrated to 2.0.4 and am now getting the following error when trying to connect (where my 1.19.6 worked perfectly fine) `Unable to send artifact without a datastore configured.`.

In my config file I have `'store.type'=> 'phpsession'` But this remains unchanged since 1.19! I can see this error is generated in HTTPArtifact.php but I must be honest and say I don't understand why its trying HTTPArtifacts and what has possibly changed that now requires a change??

I'm using a SAML connection.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, I managed to find the code issue in question ... If you compare the bottom of the `startSSO2()` function in `modules/saml/src/Auth/Source/SP.php` you'll notice:

```
'SingleSignOnService',
[
    Constants::BINDING_HTTP_ARTIFACT,
    Constants::BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT,
    Constants::BINDING_HTTP_POST,
]
```

Version 1.19 didn't include the top HTTP_ARTIFACT so the issue is it tries this now instead of the previous redirect.

**The solution** is to therefore comment out the Artifacts section in your `Metadata > SingleSignOnService` section.

```
'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact',
'Location' => 'https://sso-ping.ziftsolutions.com/idp/SSO.saml2',
```